# How to set window.variable in jquery ajax callback in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, coffeescript

This project uses rails + backbone-on-rails. 
I've tries this & that... but still i can't set global variable in a response callback. here's what i tried to do:
1) Initialization of variable in the same place backbone is initialized

```
$(document).ready ->
  window.current_user = null
  Notes.initialize()
```

2) to set up callback

```
  authorize: ->
    jQuery.ajax(
      type: 'POST'
      url: '/api/sessions.json'
      wait: true
      data:
        email: @get('email')
        password:  @get('password')
    ).success( (response) ->
      exports = this
      exports.current_user = response
      window.current_user = response
      `window.current_user = response`
```

3) and finally execute this method:

```
loginUser: (e)->
    e.preventDefault()
    if !@validateField('password') && !@validateField('email')
      return false
    @model.attributes  = @readAttributes()
    @$('#errors').text()
    @model.authorize() # call a method defined above
    console.warn window.current_user
    if window.current_user
      @$('#errors').text('You\'ve successfuly logged in ' )
    else
      @$('#errors').text('Wrong email/password!')
```

output of `console.warn window.current_user` is `null`
How should i use this global variable?
PS. response from server is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved in only by changing 1) to

```
$(document).ready ->
  window.current_user =
    name: ""
    company: ""
    created_at: ""
    email: ""
    facebook: ""
    id: ""
    license_id: ""
    linkedin: ""
    password_digest: ""
    phone: ""
    title: ""
    twitter: ""
    updated_at: ""
    web: ""
  Notes.initialize()
```

Didn't find any other way yet...